# How do I clean-up the Print > PDF menu on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac

I recently installed an application, Together, on OS X and then decided I didn't want to purchase it.  With 99% of the applications I install, all I need to do is remove them from the Applications folder to uninstall.  However, I noticed that this particular application added an item to the main drop down menu *Print > PDF list*, "Print PDF to Together"  I also noticed other applications have done the same.  So, how do I clean-up this menu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those PDF Workflows are in :

- /Library/PDF Services
- ~/Library/PDF Services

Just delete the ones provided by Together.

By default, I got those ones in `/Library/PDF Services` :

- Mail PDF.workflow
- Save As PDF-X.workflow
- Save PDF to Web Receipts Folder.pdfworkflow
- Save PDF to iPhoto.workflow

And nothing in `~/Library/PDF Services`

Comment: Wonderful!  Not only do I feel better with the remants removed.  I learned something useful.  I had no idea those were Workflows.  Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI, still works w/ El Capitan circa 2018. One would expect it to work but hey, just in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 0):

it also worked in High Sierra, thanks
I needed to open go in the "/" directory with "go to" in the finder, and delete from there

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1085894)